# How to Change block.tpl.php

Tags: 7

I created my own bootstrap sub theme and wondering how can I edit the following line:

```
<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h2>
```

to

```
<h3<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h3>
```

As you can see, I want to change the h2 tag to h3 tag.

The code above can be found under `bootstrap/theme/block`. But I believe that it's not a good idea to edit it directly on this location, unless I'm mistaken.

I know that `html.tpl.php` or `page.tpl.php` can be copied from `bootstrap/theme/system` folder to `mytheme/templates` but wondering how can I do the same with `block.tpl.php`.

Any ideas?

Note: I'm using bootstrap 3.0.

Comment: you should be able to copy block.tpl.php just the same as html.tpl.php, etc to your subtheme and then make the changes you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying the template file from the bootstrap theme to your subtheme, and making the changes in the subtheme should work just fine.
Just note to clear the caches.